# Is there a way to make a web map with custom areas that display custom info at addresses?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to make a map for work with our prices for different areas. Basically I would like to be able to add areas to a map so that if I search an address depending what area it is in will tell me the various prices. Is this possible?

I have tried using google map API tutorials but can only add a coloured area that doesn't really do much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very possible. Store your areas as an array containing sets of coordinate pairs. Each area with its pricing. You can use [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) to draw the boundaries using real-world GPS coordinates. You can export the polygon shapes you create to JSON data.

Use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to lookup a street address and retrieve the GPS coordinates.

Use [Point In Polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/point-in-polygon) class to check which polygon the GPS coordinate belongs in (if any) and assess the price.